# Selenium Grid: set chrome *binary* path

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

> Note: I am not asking about setting the path of the chrome**driver**.

I want to run a Selenium node with a specific version of Chromium as opposed to the default Chrome installed on the system. The [webdriver doc](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location) says I would need to pass a `ChromeOptions` object, but this is obviosuly impossible to do on the command line.

I've tried manually adding a JSON that represents `ChromeOptions` to the command line (like below), but it does not have any effect.

```
java.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=5,chromeOptions={binary:./chromium/chrome.exe} -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe
```

(I've tried all different ways of quoting the JSON, but it is simply not used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has not been made clear in the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2610) filed for this nor the documentation is that a new capability key "`chrome_binary`" has been added to specifically support this. See [commit 41a9d29](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/41a9d29bc3bb6f4d8d4ad25b291fadb99619a1c8).

This key can be used in the `-browser` argument used to start a node and the node will build the `ChromeOption` for you.

Comment: This is helpful, but can you provide an example?