# cannot find Chrome binary with JSON configuration file

Tags: java, json, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium with Java and executing tests with JUnit. It keeps telling me

> cannot find Chrome binary

Binary location is not standard because I need to test multiple versions. I precise that Chrome.exe launcher exists at specified JSON location...
It looks like the driver still searching at the standard location.

I've got the JSON configuration file:

```
{
   "capabilities":[
      {
         "browserName":"chrome",
         "platform":"WINDOWS",
         "chromeOptions":{
            "binary":"C:/path/chrome_binary.exe"
         },
         "maxInstance":1
      }
   ],
   "configuration":{
      "cleanUpCycle":2000,
      "timeout":30000,
      "register":true,
      "hubPort":4444,
      "hubHost":"hub.location.net",
      "maxSessions":1
   }
}
```

As you can see I'm on Windows so I tried path with slashes and backslashes but it doesn't work in either way.
ChromeOptions object should be okay, I used [this official documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Command line is:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role webdriver -nodeConfig path/to/conf.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path/to/chromedriver.exe
```

In the code, I'm creating RemoteWebDriver objects and I'm only passing browser, version and platform. It works well with Firefox. For example in JSON node configuration I've got the firefox_binary set and in code, I don't pass it to DesiredCapabilities. Selenium can still use the remote web driver I launched with the command above.

Thanks !

Comment: does file exists at that path?

Comment: Yes, of course. I edit

Comment: Shouldn't this be `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path/to/chromedriver.exe` your windows style path? Or do you need edit?

Comment: It's the binary not the driver sorry

Comment: how do you call this JSON configuration? I read from command line, but exactly from which directory? please, try a relative path instead of an absolute one

Comment: Didn't work. I updated my question for some precisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. Didn't see it on any documentation as they all talk about `binary` or `chromeOptions`.

The answer was here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33151376/4675568, many thanks to him and in a nutshell: No `chromeOptions`, just `chrome_binary` key like firefox.

```
"capabilities": [{
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "chrome_binary":"C:/path/to/chrome_binary.exe",
  "maxInstance":1
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe should work it apply this change

```
"binary":"C://path//chromedriver.exe"
```

**EDIT 1**

try with this JSON configuration file:

```
{
   "capabilities":[
      {
         "browserName":"chrome",
         "platform":"WINDOWS",
         "binary":"C:/path/chrome_binary.exe"
         "maxInstance":1
      }
   ],
   "configuration":{
      "cleanUpCycle":2000,
      "timeout":30000,
      "register":true,
      "hubPort":4444,
      "hubHost":"hub.location.net",
      "maxSessions":1
   }
}
```

eventually, try also to escape the "/" as examples below:

```
"binary":"C://path//chrome_binary.exe"
```

or

```
"binary":"C:\/path\/chrome_binary.exe"
```

Comment: Didn't work. BTW its path/to/chrome_binary.exe, sorry, could be weird for someone reading the answer. I edited my question

Comment: and if you try `"binary":"C:\/path\/chrome_driver.exe"` ?

Comment: @buzz2buzz I updated my answer with a new solution, please try it

Answer (score 0):

Paths in Windows use backward slashes:

```
"binary":"C:\\path\\chrome_binary.exe"
```